# How to pass new data to onCreateLoader

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I have an Activity that implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. The CursorLoader feeds into a RecyclerView (think ListView). So inside `onLoadFinished` I swap the data inside my adapter.

Imagine the data has to do with stock performance for a day. Now I have a Spinner that allows the user to choose a day. And when the user changes day I want the data to change. So I am thinking that the Loader needs to be able to listen to the parameter. How do I do that? Per the documentation of `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader` I am not sure if calling it inside my spinner’s `onItemSelected` will do that trick. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And when the user changes day I want the data to change. So I am
>   thinking that the Loader needs to be able to listen to the parameter

to me, it sounds like you want to requery your database again when those data change. you can use [restartLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29). You have to possibility to provide a different `id`, which can be used as identifiers for the specific loader. From the documentaion:

> Starts a new or restarts an existing Loader in this manager, registers
>   the callbacks to it, and (if the activity/fragment is currently
>   started) starts loading it.